# Comparing differences to standard deviations

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of values from B3 to G3.

I wanted to find the standard deviation and did so using

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") = WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B3:G3"))

But I need to find the difference between B3 and C3, C3 and D3, etc. and then compare it to the standard deviation above. How do I create a loop to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
Sub mycalc()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range("B3:G3")
    ws.Range("A1") = WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(rng)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To rng.Cells.Count
      rng.Cells(2, i).Value = rng.Cells(1, i).Value - rng.Cells(1, i + 1).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

This code is very much self explanatory. You should populate the interior of the loop.